# Update Database upto 24 hours

Tags: php, mysql, hitcounter

I'm trying to make a hit counter where I want to collect total hits for 24 hours. This 24 hours should be a fixed value regardless to the end user's time zone. Within 24 hours the database should be updated with +1 hit counts and once the 24 hour time scale achieved the timer should be reset.

Here is what I'm trying:

```
$timer = TIME_NOW - 60*60*24;
if ($timer < TIME_NOW)

    $db->query("UPDATE settings SET value=value+1 WHERE name='hits_today'");
}
else
{
    $db->query("UPDATE settings SET value=0 WHERE name='hits_today'");
}
```

Here `TIME_NOW` is a constant defined as `time()`

I've searched alot this site but I didn't find any answer to this question, please help, how can I go about this?

Thanks!

Comment: `TIME_NOW` - I take it you've already declared it as a constant?

Comment: Hi Fred, Yes you're right.

Comment: Since you're subtracting from `TIME_NOW` to get `$timer`, how would you expect it (`$timer`) to ever be anything but less than `TIME_NOW`?

Comment: What does that statement look like?

Comment: Also have a look at http://www.thetricky.net/php/Compare%20dates%20with%20PHP and http://www.highlystructured.com/comparing_dates_php.html might be of help to understand how time differences work.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: The framework I am using has built by someone so I don't know where exactly this has been declared but I know the `TIME_NOW` is actually equal to `time()`

Comment: Ok, well have a look at the links I gave you. You'll more than likely need to use `strtotime` to convert the time.

Comment: Thanks Fred but can you please show me an answer how to use `strtotime` on my case?

Comment: TBH, I have a real hard time with date/time stuff, so it will prove to be difficult to give you an definite answer. Just look at the links, and then echo out the variables and if they show up as intended, you would have found the formula that you need. I spent 2 **days** trying to figure something out myself, and I don't want to spend the same amount of time with yours LOL!

Comment: Let's start with this: What is the actual problem that you're having? Are you always hitting the first condition? Are you always hitting the second? Are you getting an error? Have you done `var_dump(TIME_NOW);` and `var_dump($timer);` to inspect the values?

Comment: You'd probably need something like `$now = TIME_NOW; $timer = TIME_NOW - 60*60*24; if ($timer < $now){...}` and give it a starting point.

Comment: Why not do this in a more robust way and insert this sort of metric into its own table with timestamps.  Than you can query it any way you like. Also, I think you would need to reset value to 1 instead of zero or else you would not be counting the current hit.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to store somewhere the starting time for timer. Then you can make this check in PHP working. Without it you'll never now how much time have really passed since last check.

Alternative solution 1: create a field with timer value in DB. Then create ON UPDATE trigger on settings table which will check time, i.E. if it's a new day, update this time then reset counter.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER update_counter
AFTER UPDATE ON settings
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   SET TIMER = (SELECT value FROM settings WHERE name='hits_timer' LIMIT 1);
   IF (TIMER < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) THEN
       UPDATE settings SET value=NOW() WHERE name='hits_timer';
       UPDATE settings SET value=0 WHERE name='hits_today';
   END IF;
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Alternative solution 2: Similiar to the first but use CRON jobs triggered at some certain hour (midnight, 1AM, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

I have a very simple solution for you, if you're willing to have a table dedicated to hitcount instead of storing your hitcount in a settings table...

```
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| date     | date    | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| hitcount | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

To update your hitcount just do

```
INSERT INTO `hitcount` VALUES (CURDATE(), 1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE hitcount = hitcount + 1;
```

This way, not only do you not need to reset the counter, but you have daily stats too!!!

Note: Regarding the end user's time zone, you cannot reliably get this information from server-side (you can try to determine someone's location using IP, but it's unreliable). So you'd need to obtain that from the user somehow (e.g. using javascript from the user's browser, or get the user to input this and you save it somewhere)

If you really want to use the user's timezone for dates, it can get much more complicated, and I don't really recommend doing it. Just use the server's date.

Update:
Depending on what you are actually trying to achieve (which your question doesn't give us, you only asked about implementation), there are numerous ways of dealing with it. My answer is an interpretation of your question using the 24hrs as a hint that you want to reset the counter daily.